# Multiplying Dataframe by Column Value

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm currently trying to multiply a dataframe of local currency values and converting it to its relevant Canadian value by multiplying its relevant FX rate.

However, I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12252,) (1021,)

This is the code I'm working with right now. It works when I have a handful rows of data, but keeps getting the ValueError once I use it on the full file (1022 rows of data incl. headers).

```
import pandas as pd
Local_File = ('RawData.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(Local_File, sheet_name = 'Local')
df2 = df.iloc[:,[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]].multiply(df['FX Spot Rate'],axis='index')
print (df2)
```

My dataframe looks something like this with 1022 rows of data (incl. header)

[image: SampleData]

Appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11 entries, 0 to 10
dtypes: float64(12)
memory usage: 1.1 KB

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1],
                       'B': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1],
                       'C': [9, 7, 4, 3, 9]})


    A   B   C
0   1   1   9
1   2   2   7
2   3   3   4
3   3   3   3
4   1   1   9

df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].multiply(df['A'][:], axis="index")

df

    A   B   C
0   1   1   9
1   2   4   14
2   3   9   12
3   3   9   9
4   1   1   9
```

Comment: Thanks! But still getting this error: 

//ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13273,) (1021,)

Comment: Can you try adding [:] after your df['FX Spot Rate'] to make sure it uses all rows?

Comment: Thanks - appreciate your help. But unfortunately I'm still running into the same value error.